# What should be the approach to stream Mongo collection to Kafka topic using vertx?

Tags: java, mongodb, stream, apache-kafka, vert.x

I have a MongoDB collection. I want to stream a subset of this collection (based on some query) to a Kafka topic using Vert.x.

So far I have created a Vert.x verticle for `KafkaWriteStream` which seems to work with dummy hard coded strings.

Unfortunately, I am not sure on how to get the stream of documents from MongoDB which could be later streamed to *Kafka* using the dedicated verticle.

How can I approach this? Does anyone have any relevant links or info?

Answer (score 1):

The [Vert.x Mongo Client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java/#_finding_documents_in_batches) module allows to get a `ReadStream` out of a Mongo query.

When you have it, along with your `KafkaWriteStream`, you can start reading the data from Mongo and sending it to Kafka.

Beware of backpressure though: don't overwhelm the Kafka client if Mongo loads data too fast. Your algo should look like:

```
readstream.handler(data -> {
  transformedData = transform(data); // your own transformations
  writestream.write(transformedData);
    if (writestream.writeQueueFull()) {
      readstream.pause();
      writestream.drainHandler(done -> {
        readstream.resume();
      });
    }
});
```